# query remote windows 2012 servers to see if they're in waiting for a reboot status after applying windows updates

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

Is there a way, using powershell or otherwise, to query a remote computer and see if it has had windows updates applied and is in waiting to reboot state? Any additional information would be useful too, such as has it entered the 15 minutes will force restart period or when were the updates applied.

windows 2012 servers will not restart after applying windows updates if a user is logged on.
sometimes you remote in, unlock it, and it will then reboot under you in the middle of the day on a production server... or critical updates get held up and not applied.

I understand this this behavior can be modified somewhat with GPOs or registry hacks but that is not my question.

Comment: Add all your servers in Server Manager somewhere.  Somehow server manager is able to report pending reboots.

Comment: thanks for that suggestion. that probably is a viable solution for some facing this issue but I am looking for something scriptable.

Comment: I found the following script http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-PendingReboot-Query-bdb79542 that get machines with pending reboots. combined with grabbing the date of the last windows update it may provide enough info to meet my needs.